# Pause button does not fade out after video starts playing in youtube video player fragment

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using android-youtube api in my android project. I am using youtube fragment to play a youtube video.
Along with that video, I am playing other media (eg imageview) side-by-side. (I am aware that the youtube fragment should be always on top, so the problem is not related to this constraint).
I am able to play the video successfully, but the problem is, after video starts playing, the pause button does not fade out. It keeps showing that button. It seems like it fades out, but immediately after it disappears, it reappears.
I am not getting any logs related to this (not even in system log). However, when I play video fragment in full layout, there is no such problem.
In short, the problem occurs only when I play video along with some other media side-by-side. I didn't find any work around for this particular problem, so I don't have any code related to this problem.
How do I get rid of this issue?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Maybe the reason why `youtube` requests full screen is the fact that the button shows - hides with the change of focus. So, when you add your media the media get focus -> youtube loose focus and `BANG!` play button re-appears. Can you force the focus to youtube? (I have never used this API but the way you describe it  seems to related with something like that.) An other way to test that the focus is the problem a) add your media with a delay OR b) add youtube second.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in case of lost focus youtube video does not play at all, and this is not the case here.When i apply any focus related code (such as requestFocus() or bringToFront()) video does not play.